# vim-plug: install plugins on startup not working properly on Ubuntu

Tags: vimrc, linux-ubuntu, plugin-vim-plug

per the recommendation in the `vim-plug` wiki: https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/wiki/extra, I've added the following snippet to my vimrc:

```
" Install missing plugins on Vim startup
autocmd VimEnter *
  \  if len(filter(values(g:plugs), '!isdirectory(v:val.dir)'))
  \|   PlugInstall --sync | q
  \| endif
```

This does indeed cause any missing plugins to be installed on Vim startup, but on subsequent launches on Ubuntu (18.04 LTS, with apt's version of vim and a version I built from source) the body of the if statement continues to evaluate to 1 (verified with `echomsg`), so the plugin installation screen flashes every time I open vim.

This is not the case on macOS; once the plugins are installed for the first time, the body of the if statement no longer evaluates to 1, and the `PlugInstall` screen no longer displays.

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Can't reproduce, it works fine for me. You need to check result of `filter(...)`, it's not empty.

Comment: You should provide us the result of the `filter` command so that we can have an idea of what is happening. Also if I may add my two cents: Is it really worth it to add to your vimrc an autocommand which will be executed every time you start vim and which is already causing some issues just to run `PlugInstall` once which you could do manually or from the script which installs your dotfiles to a new machine? And finally your autocommands should _always_ be in a [`:h :augroup`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#%3Aaugroup).

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. Checking the output of `filter` helped diagnose the problem, my vimrc also contained the following line: 
```" If installed using Homebrew
Plug '/usr/local/opt/fzf'```
which referred to a program that wasn‘t installed but also couldn‘t be installed by `vim-plug`. Installing it properly fixed the problem.

statox, I will consider your comments about including this section at all, it might not be worth the trouble. Thank you both!

Comment: @PaulRoever Please post that as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the output of `filter` helped diagnose the problem, my vimrc also contained the following line:

```
" If installed using Homebrew
Plug '/usr/local/opt/fzf'
```

which referred to a program ([fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf)) that wasn't installed but also couldn't be installed by `vim-plug`. Installing it [properly](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#as-vim-plugin) fixed the problem.

Comment: Nice to see that you found the solution to your problem. Don't hesitate to mark your answer as accepted when you can.

Comment: Ah, yes. I work around this by checking for the executable when adding the plugin: `if executable('go') | Plug 'fatih/vim-go', {'for': 'go'} | endif` etc.